# tengo un error en una nueva medida en dax recorrer kilometros por dia (Power BI desktop)

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hola buena tarde a todos he estado tratando de resolver un problema para mostrar los kilómetros recorridos por vehículo al dia

tengo una tabla donde se registran los tickets de combustible la cual consta de varios campos, pero los principales son los siguientes economico, fecha_carga y el odometro_dia

lo que necesito es obtener los kilometrajes recorridos por cada vehículo en ese día, por ejemplo la unidad con numero economico 592 del dia 02/01/2023 cargo gasolina y su odometro de carga fue 175,885 y el día 05/01/2023 fue de 176,142 por lo que en una nueva columna deberia haber (km recorridos) ----> (odometro_carga del 05/01/2023) - (odometro_carga del 02/01/2023) lo cual quedaria para el dia 05/01/2303 = 257

1.- Detalles que los dias no son consecutivos, pueden pasar varios dias hasta la proxima carga,

quedando de la siguente manera:

km recorridos =

var _max = maxx(filter(Table , [economico] = before([economico]) && [feach_carga] < before([feach_carga]) ), [feach_carga])

devolución

if(isblank(_max), 0, [odometro_carga] - maxx(filter(Table , [economico] = before([economico]) && [feach_carga] =_max ), [odometro_carga]) )

el proble es que power bi no me reconoce "BEFORE" por que no es una función nativa lo cambie por "EARLIER" para continuar y ver si daba otro error, el cual me sale:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al cambiarla por
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me dice que la sintaxis del if no es correcta, alguna opcion para obtener lo que necesito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de analizar un poco encontre la solución, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
recorrido = 

var _max = maxx(filter('vehiculos reg_combustible' , [economico] = 
EARLIER([economico]) && [fecha_carga] < EARLIER([fecha_carga]) ), 
[fecha_carga])

return

if(isblank(_max), 0, [odometro_carga] - maxx(filter('vehiculos reg_combustible' , [economico] = 
EARLIER([economico]) && [fecha_carga] =_max ), [odometro_carga]) )
```